# How to include an ExpandableListActivity in a View

Tags: android, android-intent, expandablelistview

I have a View with TextViews, ImageViews,... but I want to include some data using an ExpandableList. I don't know how to include this ExpandableList in my View with the other data.

My objetive:

[image: MyView]

I have all component in one View except the ExpandableList, that I have in other Activity:

> **OfferDetailsActivity** (This is the Activity that shows the View and from here I want to call to ExpandableList)

```
public class OfferDetailsActivity extends Activity{

final public static String OFERTA = "oferta";
private Oferta oferta = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.offer_details);             

    oferta = (Oferta)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(OFERTA);

    View view = new View(this.getBaseContext());

    LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = linflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_details, null);

    // poblamos la lista de elementos           
    TextView precio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.precio_offer_details);
    precio.setText(oferta.getPrecio());

    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen_offer_details);
    imagen.setImageBitmap(new GetImages().downloadFile(oferta.getImagen()));

    TextView cabecera = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cabecera_offer_details);
    cabecera.setText(oferta.getCabecera());

    TextView descripcion = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_offer_details);
    descripcion.setText(oferta.getDescripcion());                                                   

    setContentView(view);

}
```

}

> **ExpandableList**

```
public class ExpandableList extends ExpandableListActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.offer_details);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.           
                new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                   
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","Group Item " + i ); // the key and it's value.
        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;
}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();
        child.put( "Sub Item", "Sub Item " + n );           
        secList.add( child );
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }        
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();         
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
    System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
    return true;
}

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

> **offer_details.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow>   
    <TextView android:id="@+id/precio_offer_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12px" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/cabecera_offer_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12px" />                      
</TableRow>

<TableRow>        
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagen_offer_details"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/descripcion_offer_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="10px" />                                          
</TableRow>                               

<TextView android:id="@+id/texto3"      
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="10px" 
    android:text="texto3"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/texto4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="10px" 
    android:text="texto4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code from the expandable list activity into the other qctivity and put the necessary bits in the other activities XML file and you should be fine...  is there some issue you're having that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: Maybe inheritance issues... One of the Activities extends of Activity and the other extends of ExpandableListActivity. I will try to do that you say.

Comment: The only change you might have to make is to find the expandable list view (findViewById)  since Activity doesn't assume the id.  And the method you call to set the adapter is different (setAdapter vs setListAdapter if I recall correctly).

Comment: If I move the code from ExpandableList.class to OfferDetailsActivity.class appears compilation errors because, for example, methods "createGroupList()" and "createChildList()" are only available if you extends from ExpandableListActivity. To solve this problem I decided keep the 2 classes and in OfferDetailsActivity.class write this lines to call the other class before setContentView(view). Don't works correctly:  ExpandableListView oExpandableListView = new ExpandableListView(this.getBaseContext());
   oExpandableListView.setAdapter(new ExpandableList().getExpandableListAdapter());